# Building R package causes R to crash

Tags: r, crash, package, devtools

I'm trying to diagnose what's causing R to crash when I try to build a package I've created and I'm not sure what steps to take next.

I initially created the package using RStudio and `devtools`. After writing several functions, I ran `devtools::document()`, however this caused RStudio to crash. When I reopened the project, `document()` ran without a crash, but then RStudio crashed after `devtools::build()`. I reopened RStudio and this time `build()` ran without an error and I was able to click `Install and Restart` to install the package. After clicking `Install and Restart` RStudio sometimes crashes and sometimes doesn't.

I decided to try the `build` and `document` commands by running R directly without RStudio. I removed the `man` folder and `NAMESPACE` file from the project directory. Then, after setting the working directory to the directory for the package, I ran `devtools::document()`, which ran without error and generated a `man` folder and `NAMESPACE` file. Then I ran `devtools::build()` which crashed R. The crash message is below. However, when I restarted R and ran `build()` again, it ran without error. I then ran `R CMD INSTALL` from the command line and it installed the package without error.

I'm not sure what steps to take next. All of the functions in the package run without error when I create and use them directly in R scripts. Could there be something in the `roxygen` documentation comments for one or more functions that's causing the crash?

In case it might be helpful to know, the package includes a file `imports.r` with the following imports:

```
#' @importFrom fst read.fst
#' @importFrom lubridate today
#' @import readr
#' @import readxl
#' @import dplyr
NULL
```

I can provide other information, such as details about and code for the package, crash logs, etc. I'm on a Macbook Pro running Sierra (10.12.6), R 3.4.2, devtools 1.13.3.9000, roxygen2 6.0.1, and RStudio 1.1.383.

Here's the crash message from R after the running `build()` for the first time:

```
 *** caught illegal operation ***
address 0x7fff9f32eae4, cause 'illegal opcode'

Traceback:
 1: process_initialize(self, private, command, args, commandline,     stdout, stderr, cleanup, echo_cmd, windows_verbatim_args,     windows_hide_window)
 2: .subset2(public_bind_env, "initialize")(...)
 3: process$new(command, args, commandline, echo_cmd = echo_cmd,     windows_verbatim_args = windows_verbatim_args, windows_hide_window = windows_hide_window,     stdout = "|", stderr = "|")
 4: run(bin, args = real_cmdargs, stdout_line_callback = real_callback(stdout),     stderr_line_callback = real_callback(stderr), stdout_callback = real_block_callback,     stderr_callback = real_block_callback, echo_cmd = echo, echo = show,     spinner = spinner, error_on_status = fail_on_status, timeout = timeout)
 5: force(code)
 6: with_envvar(env, run(bin, args = real_cmdargs, stdout_line_callback = real_callback(stdout),     stderr_line_callback = real_callback(stderr), stdout_callback = real_block_callback,     stderr_callback = real_block_callback, echo_cmd = echo, echo = show,     spinner = spinner, error_on_status = fail_on_status, timeout = timeout))
 7: eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
 8: eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
 9: with.default(options, with_envvar(env, run(bin, args = real_cmdargs,     stdout_line_callback = real_callback(stdout), stderr_line_callback = real_callback(stderr),     stdout_callback = real_block_callback, stderr_callback = real_block_callback,     echo_cmd = echo, echo = show, spinner = spinner, error_on_status = fail_on_status,     timeout = timeout)))
10: with(options, with_envvar(env, run(bin, args = real_cmdargs,     stdout_line_callback = real_callback(stdout), stderr_line_callback = real_callback(stderr),     stdout_callback = real_block_callback, stderr_callback = real_block_callback,     echo_cmd = echo, echo = show, spinner = spinner, error_on_status = fail_on_status,     timeout = timeout)))
11: run_r(options)
12: callr::rcmd_safe(..., env = env)
13: with_build_tools(callr::rcmd_safe(..., env = env), required = required)
14: rcmd_build_tools(cmd, c(path, args), wd = out_dir, show = !quiet,     echo = !quiet, fail_on_status = TRUE, required = FALSE)
15: force(code)
16: withr::with_temp_libpaths(rcmd_build_tools(cmd, c(path, args),     wd = out_dir, show = !quiet, echo = !quiet, fail_on_status = TRUE,     required = FALSE))
17: pkgbuild::build(path = path, dest_path = dest_path, binary = binary,     vignettes = vignettes, manual = manual, args = args, quiet = quiet,     ...)
18: devtools::build()

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

Comment: Are you using windows and your username contains non-ASCII characters?

Comment: I'm on a Mac and my username is all ascii with no spaces or hyphens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this out: Marcus Klik, the developer of the [fst package](https://github.com/fstpackage), was able to track down and fix the issue. The [github issue page](https://github.com/fstpackage/fst/issues/109) has the details. Scroll down to Marcus Klik's comment near the end of the thread for the key findings.